# Eager Loading Multiple Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have three objects which are related as so:

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :program
end

class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :sites
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :programs
end
```

In my `Sites index` view, when looping through all of my sites I want to displiay `Edit` and `Destroy` buttons, but only if the `current_user` owns the site:

```
- if current_user == site.program.user || current_user.try(:admin?)
  = icon_link_to "edit", 'Edit', edit_program_site_path(site.program, site), :class => "btn btn-primary"
  = icon_link_to "trash", "Delete", site, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger'
```

This code fails because the program and user objects are nil.

I know that in my controller I need something like the following:

```
@sites = Site.includes(:programs).all
```

Which would solve the problem of accessing the `site.program`, however I am not sure how I can also include the `user`.

Model changes are acceptable if the current schema is considered incorrect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use,

```
Site.joins(:program).where('programs.user_id=?', current_user.id).includes(:programs).all
```

Comment: Good answer. I started using `Site.joins(:program => :user).page(params[:page])` but this fetches every user when I only need to current one. However I need to show sites to other users as well.